# Reliable/robust method of ripping attachments from a POP/IMAP/Exchange mailbox

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, imap, attachment

I'm looking for some fresh ideas after a bit of a google and would love your opinion:

I have an email address hosted in exchange that will receive attachments on a regular basis. I would like a reliable way of downloading the attachments and placing the email in a folder. The last bit is not important, just to keep things organised.

I had considered Outlook addons on 2012R2, running Thunderbird on an RHEL server but I want to avoid using a consumer email client and was wondering if there was a lighter more robust tool/method of doing this that could be left alone for months without failing.

Im not bothered on how the mail is handled IMAP, POP, MAPI/RPC, ActiveSync or a transport rule in Exchange 2010 that forward to a non exchange external email address.

I would prefer something running on RHEL/CentOS/UbuntuServer but Windows is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always it depends. Should the original messages remain on the hosted Exchange or not?
Regardless the de facto Linux method of synching (new) messages from a remote email box is `fetchmail`. That allows you to do either.

Then have `fetchmail` feed the email messages to a script that strips the attachments from the message bodies and store them in an archive directory, for instance using [`ripMIME`](http://www.pldaniels.com/ripmime/) or something similar.